# Does every irreducible representation of a compact group occur in tensor products of a faithful representation and its dual?

Tags: lie-groups, rt.representation-theory

(Previously posted on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26909/does-every-irreducible-representation-of-a-compact-group-occur-in-tensor-products) with no answers.)

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $V$ a faithful (complex, continuous, finite-dimensional) representation of it. Is it true that every (complex, continuous, finite-dimensional) irreducible representation of $G$ occurs in $V^{\otimes n} (V^{\ast})^{\otimes m}$ for some $n, m$?

The proof I know for finite groups doesn't seem to easily generalize. I want to apply Stone-Weierstrass, but can't figure out if the characters I get will always separate points (in the space of conjugacy classes). Ben Webster in his answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40926/a-faithful-representation-generates-all-the-other-representations) seems to be suggesting that this follows from the first part of Peter-Weyl, but I don't see how this works.

Certainly the corresponding algebra of characters separates points whenever the eigenvalues of an element $g \in G$ acting on $V$ determine its conjugacy class (since one can get the eigenvalues from an examination of the exterior powers). Does this always happen?

Comment: You can apply Stone-Weierstrass not to characters but to matrix coefficients (and for functions on $G$ not for functions on conjugacy classes).

Comment: @Torsten: right. That implies that the matrix coefficients I get are dense, and then... oh, then I apply orthogonality for matrix coefficients. Okay, now I have to understand this result (I've only used orthogonality of characters in the past). 

Comment: See GTM98 (Representations of Compact Lie groups), p.137 for a proof using Peter-Weyl.

Comment: @shenghao: I think Peter-Weyl is stronger than what I need. As Torsten indicates, the fact that $G$ is already assumed to have a faithful representation means I can use Stone-Weierstrass to prove the part of Peter-Weyl that is relevant. 

Comment: what about "for all sufficiently large m,n" ?

Comment: @Vivek: that is false. Consider the case of $\text{U}(1)$. 

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can mimic the standard finite group argument. Recall that, if $X$ and $Y$ are two finite-dimensional representations of $G$, with characters $\chi_X$ and $\chi_Y$, then $\dim \mathrm{Hom}_G(X,Y) = \int_G \overline{\chi_X}  \chi_Y$, where the integral is with respect to Haar measure normalized so that $\int_G 1 =1$. The proof of this is exactly as in the finite case.

Now, let $W=1 \oplus V \oplus \overline{V}$. Your goal is to show that, for any nonzero representation $Y$, $\mathrm{Hom}(W^{\otimes N}, Y)$ is nonzero for $N$ sufficiently large. So you need to analyze $\int (1+\chi_V + \overline{\chi_V})^N \chi_W$ for $N$ large. Just as in the finite group case, we are going to split this into an integral near the identity, and an exponentially decaying term everywhere else.

I'm going to leave a lot of the analytic details to you, but here is the idea. Let $d=\dim V$. The function $f:=1+\chi_V + \overline{\chi_V}$ makes sense on the entire unitary group of $V$, of which $G$ is a subgroup. On a unitary matrix with eigenvalues $(e^{i \theta_1}, \cdots, e^{i \theta_d})$, we have $f=1+2 \sum \cos \theta_i$. In particular, for an element $g$ in the Lie algebra of $G$ near the identity, we have
$$f(e^g) = (2n+1) e^{-K(g) + O(|g|^4)}$$
where $K$ is $\mathrm{Tr}(g^* g) = \sum \theta_i^2$.
And, for $g$ near the identity, $\chi_X(e^g) = d + O(|g|)$. So the contribution to our integral near the identity can be approximated by
$$\int_{\mathfrak{g}} \left( (2n+1) e^{-K(g) + O(|g|^4)} \right)^N (d+ O(|g|) \approx (2n+1)^N d \int_{\mathfrak{g}} e^{-K(\sqrt{N} g)} = \frac{(2n+1)^N d}{N^{\dim G/2}} C$$
where $C$ is a certain Gaussian integral, and includes some sort of a factor concerning the determinant of the quadratic form $K$. You also need to work out what the Haar measure of $G$ turns into as a volume form on $\mathfrak{g}$ near $0$, I'll leave that to you as well.

For right now, the important point is that the growth rate is like $(2n+1)^N d$ divided by a polynomial factor. In the finite group case, that polynomial is a constant, which makes life easier, but we can live with a polynomial.

Now, look at the contribution from the rest of $G$. For any point in the unitary group $U(d)$, other than the identity, we have $|f| < 2n+1$. (To get equality, all the eigenvalues must be $1$ and, in the unitary group, that forces us to be at the identity.) So, if we break our integral into the integral over a small ball around the identity, plus an integral around everything else, the contribution of every thing else will be $O(a^N)$ with $a<2n+1$.

So, just as in the finite group case, the exponential with the larger base wins, and the polynomial in the denominator is too small to effect the argument. Joel and I discussed a similar, but harder, argument over at the [Secret Blogging Seminar](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/passage-from-compact-lie-groups-to-complex-reductive-groups/).

Comment: Very nice! I tried to mimic this argument but it is much nicer when you add in that copy of the trivial rep. 

Answer (score 10):

The answer is "yes".  This is (the compact version of) Proposition 2.20 b on page 139 of the Deligne-Milne article on Tannakian categories in *Hodge cycles, Shimura Varieties, and Motives* (Springer LNM 900).  You can find [a scan on Milne's web page](http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1982b.pdf).

**Edit:** You can reconstruct a self-contained proof of the algebraic tensor generation statement by mixing Proposition 3.1 from Deligne's [Absolute Hodge article](http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1982a.pdf) with the lemma in section 3.5 of Waterhouse's *Introduction to Affine Group Schemes* (GTM 66):

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, and $V$ a faithful representation.  If $W$ is an $n$-dimensional representation of $G = \operatorname{Spec} A$, then $W$ embeds by the comodule structure map into $A^{\oplus n}$, where $A^{\oplus n} = W \otimes A$ has comodule structure given by $id_W \otimes \Delta$.  The comodule structure map is an $A$-comodule homomorphism by the axiom relating coactions with comultiplication, and the injectivity follows from the counit axiom.  If $W$ is irreducible, then its embedding in $A^{\oplus n}$ lies in one copy of $A$, so $W$ can be viewed as a sub-$A$-comodule of $A$.

$G$ is a closed subvariety of $GL(V)$, which is in turn a closed subvariety of $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ by the map $g \mapsto (g, g^{-1})$, where $B = \operatorname{Sym}(\operatorname{End}(V) \oplus \operatorname{End}(V^\vee))$.  This yields a surjection $\pi: B \twoheadrightarrow A$ of $A$-comodule algebras.  $B$ is inductively filtered by sub-$GL(V)$-modules $B_{k,\ell}$ of polynomials whose degree in $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is at most $k$ and whose degree in $\operatorname{End}(V^\vee)$ is at most $\ell$.  Since $W$ is a finite dimensional sub-$A$-comodule of $A$, it is contained in the image of some $B_{k,\ell}$ under $\pi$.

If $C_{k,\ell} \subset B$ is the space of bihomogeneous polynomials of degree $(k,\ell)$, then $B_{k,\ell} \cong \bigoplus_{r\leq k, s \leq \ell} C_{r,s}$ as $GL(V)$-modules.  Also $C_{r,s}$ is a $GL(V)$-module quotient of $C_{1,0}^{\otimes r} \otimes C_{0,1}^{\otimes s}$.  $C_{0,1}$ is a sum of copies of $V$, and $C_{1,0}$ is a sum of copies of $V^\vee$.  This yields $W$ as a quotient of $V^{\otimes k} \otimes (V^\vee)^{\otimes \ell}$ for some $k$ and $\ell$.

This reduces your question to two problems:

1. Algebrization of compact groups takes complex representations to complex representations.
2. Finite dimensional representations of compact groups are completely reducible.

Comment: Great! The proposition refers to I.3.1a. I assume that is the first part of the paper? Is there a reasonably self-contained proof of this?

Comment: You can look at page 40 of http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1982a.pdf to see this proposition.  I'm afraid this material is too foreign to me to tell if it's easy to reconstruct a self-contained proof...

Comment: This is interesting, but algebrization of compact groups seems like a little too much work to prove this result. Or is this easier than I think it is? 

Comment: I think there is an unavoidable analytic input.